# Get variable from angular service with the app component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-services, cordova-nativestorage

I have a service that has a public property called companyDetail, And in the constructor, I set its value from the native storage:

```js
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedDataService{
    public companyDetail;
    constructor( private platform:Platform, private nativeStorage: NativeStorage ){
        this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
            this.nativeStorage.getItem('company').then(res=>{
                this.companyDetail = res
            })
    })
    }
}
```

I get the `companyDetail` in the app.component file:

```js
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx';
import { SharedDataService } from './content/services/sharedData.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private sharedData:SharedDataService ){
         console.log(this.sharedData.companyDetail);
    }
}
```

But it is always logging `null` value.

Comment: Did you log the res in the SharedDataService? Maybe the response from the nativeStorage is null?
Maybe the app component is initialized before the service has finished the reading from the nativeStorage?
Why don't you use e.g Observables to subscribe to the changes?

Comment: Yes in the SharedDataService it is OK, how to use Observables?

Comment: The you should check, if the constructor in AppComponent is called before the result in the SharedDataService

https://medium.com/@zmharker/rxjs-observables-in-ionic-and-angular-apps-a-beginners-guide-181643af675e

Answer (score 0):

I think you have async problem,

I am not familiar with Ionic, this is the simple example for web.

If you can use Rxjs in your Ionic project this example should work for Ionic too.

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/internal/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedDataService{
    public companyDetail = null;
    public companyDetailSubject = new BehaviorSubject(this.companyDetail);

    constructor( private platform:Platform, private nativeStorage: NativeStorage ){
        this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
            this.nativeStorage.getItem('company').then(res=>{
                this.companyDetail = res;
                this.companyDetailSubject.next(this.companyDetail);
            })
    })
    }
}
```

and in app.component.ts

imports

```
import { filter, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

constructor

```
   constructor(private sharedData:SharedDataService ){
      this.sharedData.companyDetailSubject.pipe(
          filter(value => !!value), 
          take(1)
      ).subscribe(response => {
           console.log(response)
      })
    }
```